# Getting error of "RangeError: Invalid time value" when inputing variable within new Date()

Tags: reactjs, date, next.js, date-fns

```
function search() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { location, startDate, endDate, numOfGuests } = router.query;

  const formattedStartDate = format(new Date(startDate), "dd, MMMM yyyy");
  const formattedEndDate = format(new Date(endDate), "dd, MMMM yyyy");
  const range = `${formattedStartDate} - ${formattedEndDate}`;
  return(...);
  }

export default search;
```

Using React/Next.js.
I am trying to create a formatted date using date-fns. The problem seems that when i input the variable of `startDate` into the `new Date()` ex: `new Date(startDate)`, it gives me the error. When i manually hard code the value of `startDate` instead, it works as needed, example: `new Date("2022-01-28T05:00:00.000Z")`. I even tried making `startDate` into a string by `startDate.toString()` and still doesn't work.

`startDate` is coming from date-fns DateRangePicker allowing you to select two dates. I am then pushing it through next.js router as a query

```
const search = () => {
    router.push({
      pathname: "/search",
      query: {
        location: searchInput,
        startDate: startDate.toISOString(),
        endDate: endDate.toISOString(),
        numOfGuests,
      },
    });
  };
```

Comment: Include the code showing how `startDate` is created, so we can help you debug it.

Comment: It is working fine , as per your `startDate` it is generating the formatted date as `"28 January 22"`.

Comment: Okay updated post.

Comment: `useRouter` is a React hook, it can only be used inside a React component or another React hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. Everything works fine and the code should have worked as intended. The problem was coming from using nextJs, `useRouter()`. To access the router I needed to use `useRouter()`, example: `const router = useRouter();`. Then to access the query data i've set up within the router would be such as: `const { location, startDate, endDate, numOfGuests } = router.query;`.

To use `useRouter` it needs to be in a proper component function starting with a **capitalized** name. My problem was it was lowercased. Example ;  `function search() {...}` instead of, `function Search() {...}`. From here i will keep the file name of `search.js` lowercased for address bar router query purposes.